# Angular feature module : where should I store module related assets?

Tags: angular, assets

I am developing a feature module with Angular and I am wondering about where I should place the assets related to the module.

If I understood correctly the idea behind feature modules, it should be in an assets folder in the feature module.
This way, I could reuse this module in any app without the concern of looking for related medias in the main assets folder.

However, I was not able to find an answer to this question on Stack Overflow or on the internet.

What is the common practice in Angular?